# How do I export data into excel in R (from Console)

Tags: r, excel

I'm new to R.
I modified some data to analyze.
The data I got in Console (not saved in the Environment)
I used this code
`data.frame(table(X01Dhaka$YEAR))` to modify

and I got this in Console (that didn't save in Environment)

```
> data.frame(table(X01Dhaka$YEAR))
   Var1 Freq
1  1982    7
2  1983   36
3  1984   41
4  1985   45
5  1986   55
6  1987   31
7  1988   29
8  1989   52
9  1990   37
10 1991   51
11 1992   60
12 1993   18
13 1994   52
14 1995   57
15 1996   48
16 1997   17
17 1998    5
18 1999   45
19 2000   11
20 2001   21
21 2002   15
22 2003   23
23 2004   30
24 2005   16
25 2006   20
26 2007   15
27 2008   22
28 2009   25
29 2010   38
30 2011    3
31 2012   19
32 2013   26
33 2014   47
34 2015    2
```

Now I want this data to save as excel on my pc.  (I searched Google and Youtube but all of them export data from **Environment** and my data shows in **Console**)
I don't know what to do, how can I fix it?

Comment: It is easiest to run it again and assign the output to a variable `output <- data.frame(table(X01Dhaka$YEAR))` and then perhaps save it as a CSV file for easily reading into Excel `write.csv(output, "output_file.csv")`

Comment: In addition to the answers given, I'd recommend package *rio*. It is a wrapper around the  many format-dependent export utilities of R whose variety can be overwhelming at first. The necessary exporter is guessed from the file extension, with sensible defaults in place. In your case, it would be as easy as `export(output, file = "my_excel.xlsx")`, where **output** is your dataframe.

Comment: Results of that call is not in your environment because you did not assign it with `<-` to a named object.